# What are the laplacian operators for the three two dimensional metrics of one variable dependence?

Tags: riemannian-geometry

What are the laplacian operators from the three following two dimensional metrics of one variable dependence :

\begin{align}
(A)
&&
d\mathcal{l}^2
=
e^{2w(x_2)}
\left(
dx_1^2
+
dx_2^2
\right)
&&
\nabla_1\nabla^1
+
\nabla_2\nabla^2
=
?
\\
(B)
&&
d\mathcal{l}^2
=
\left(
e^{4w(x_2)}
dx_1^2
+
dx_2^2
\right)
&&
\nabla_1\nabla^1
+
\nabla_2\nabla^2
=
?
\\
(C)
&&
d\mathcal{l}^2
=
\left(
dx_1^2
+
e^{4w(x_2)}
dx_2^2
\right)
&&
\nabla_1\nabla^1
+
\nabla_2\nabla^2
=
?
\end{align}

My answer for all three was
\begin{align}
\nabla_1\nabla^1
+
\nabla_2\nabla^2
=
\dfrac{\partial^2}{\partial x_1^2}
+
e^{-w(x_2)}
\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x_2}
\left(
e^{w(x_2)}
\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x_2}
\right)
,
\end{align}
however I do not believe my answer is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll do (A).  Recall, that in coordinates, we have that
$$\Delta_g u=\frac{1}{\sqrt{|g|}}\partial_a\left[g^{ab}\sqrt{|g|}\partial_b[u]\right],$$
where $|g|=\det(g_{ab})$.  Note for this case $g_{ab}=e^{2w(x_2)}\delta_{ab}$, where $\delta$ is our usual Euclidean metric (i.e., it's conformally equivalent).  Then $g^{ab}=e^{-2w(x_2)}\delta^{ab}$ and $\sqrt{|g|}=e^{2w(x_2)}$ (since $|\delta|=1$, and we're in dimension $2$).  Computing, we see that
$$\Delta_g u =e^{-2w(x_0)}\partial_a\left[e^{-2w(x_2)}\delta^{ab}e^{2w(x_2)}\partial_b[u]\right]=e^{-2w(x_2)}\delta^{ab}\partial_a\partial_bu=e^{-2w(x_2)}\Delta_\delta u,$$
where $\Delta_\delta$ is our usual Euclidean Laplacian.

Comment: Is this different if I use the Christoffel symbols to calculate the Laplacian? I used $\Gamma_{a a b} = \partial_b g_{aa}$/2?

Comment: It would turn out to be the same if you use the Christoffel symbols, though it would be a longer calculation. I avoid computing Christoffel symbols at all costs normally, but in this case, they are quite simple.